# Representation of null set or empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having confusion that  how to represent null set. Yes it seems like I ask silly question. Well I know null set can be represent either $\{\}$ or $\emptyset$.

But can I write null set like $\{\emptyset\}$?

Yes this is the actually the question.

Thanks.

Comment: The set $\{\emptyset\}$ is different from the empty set $\emptyset$, since it contains one element. The two usual notations are $\emptyset$ or $\{\}$.

Comment: Also some authors, mostly in NF studies, also still use the very archaic $\Lambda$ for the empty set.

Answer (score 3):

No, because the set $\{\emptyset\}$ is not empty. It contains the null set:

$$\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}.$$

Comment: Means {Ф} will have two subset, Right?

Comment: @zonnie Yes, namely $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Isn't it confusing to have a set which has null set means nothing but still we are considering nothing as something?

Comment: @zonnie At first maybe, just like the concept of the number zero was confusing when you first learned about it in elementary school, but you get used to the idea pretty quickly. Imagine putting an empty box inside a second box. The second box is not empty, because it has an empty box inside it.

Comment: @zonnie : Putting the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ OUTSIDE the math tags causes a mismatch of font styles and sizes and neglect of proper spacing. Just write $\{\emptyset\}$ or $\{\Phi\}$ (coded as \{\emptyset\} or \{\Phi\}. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael: What's $\Phi$ in this context? Surely it's not the empty set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In fact $\Phi$ *is* being used to denote the empty set here, and it upsets me deeply.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe Russian texts still do this. At least I've seen it mostly in (older) Russian papers... Even $\Lambda$ is used sometimes for the empty set.

Comment: @Henno: I have seen $\Lambda$ used. But $\Phi$? I haven't seen that. I have seen `\O` used, but that's mostly from texts pre-$\LaTeX$ times when symbols were a bit hard to come by and people used whatever they could manage to find that looks sufficiently readable.

Comment: Question has been answered. So stay cool.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : "$\Phi$" is what I found written in the question.

Comment: @Michael: I see, I didn't look in the question's history. Sorry. And my apologies to David for five extraneous comments on his answer!

Comment: @AsafKaragila No need to apologize. I actually found the impromptu comments on the usage variances for symbols denoting the empty set fascinating. :)